# Meson build: Add dependency path for executable manually

Tags: meson-build

What I'd like to do, is rather easy: Compile a project using the Meson build system + manually including a dependency.

However, there's one dependency, which I do not want to install to `/usr/lib`, due to System Integrity Protection on Mac. (I know I can turn this off; I don't want to.)

So basically I wanna do:
`g++ -L[path_to_lib] [files...]` but use `meson` instead of `g++`.

However, this seems to be super complicated. After doing some research and unsuccessfully adding

`cc = meson.get_compiler('c')
dep = cc.find_library('granite' dirs: [ [path_to_dep] ])`

to my meson.build file (which doesn't work, as it handles libraries, not dependencies)
I'm left feeling rather dumb.

Please help!

I know I could just add the relevant path to $PATH, but that is more than overkill and I refuse to believe that there isn't another nice quick way to do so. (As is with the ancient c compiler...)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to solve your problem without modifying *meson.build* file (I mean leave granite as ordinary dependency). **meson** uses pkg-config to search for dependencies, so if you add your non-standard path containing granite package config file to `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` it will find it. And in this case granite package config file should be correct, of course, i.e. contain correct library and header paths, which should be correct if you [configure installation](https://github.com/elementary/granite) of granite with something like:

```
# Configure:
$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/some/path...
# Build:
$ make
# Install (need sudo?):
$ make install

$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/some/path...:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH

granite_dep = dependency('granite')
my_app = executable('my_app',
  dependencies : [granite_dep]
  ...
```

However, note that in case of **find_library()** according to [reference manual](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#compiler-object):

> The result object can be used just like the return value of dependency

So, it should work:

```
granite_dep = cc.find_library('granite', dirs : [path])
executable(..., dependencies : granite_dep)
```

But, I recommend standard way that utilizes pkg-config, because granite can also have dependencies that you will not be able to automatically pick up this way.